# What happens if you remove ga('send', 'pageview');?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

By a mistake I managed to remove ga('send', 'pageview'); from one of my pages. And it has been like that for a while...
Out of curiosity I wonder how important this line is, and what it actually does?

Obviously, a pageview will not be tracked for that page, but will other stuff be tracked?
What about sessions, users, etc.? Will that be tracked if this line it omitted?

If you wonder how I could forget this line on one of my pages, it is because I copy & pasted it from the index.html of a dynamic webpage that uses angulartics, and this line is not supposed to be used then.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove that line, nothing will be tracked.

The only way to track things with analytics.js is to make `ga('send', ...)` calls. If you make no `send` calls, then absolutely nothing will be tracked.

Unlike what many people seem to think, analytics.js doesn't send anything to Google Analytics unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
If that is the case, I have a follow up question though. Appearently some data was tracked. Sessions with utm source,campaign, etc that could only come from the page that missed the send call have been tracked. I am 100% sure these utm-parameters are not passed on to the main dynamic website on a possible redirect. However, I have send events on button clicks on the page that missed the initial send event, could it be that this is the reason I can see some sessions?

Comment: Yes, that could definitely be the reason. You should read this article on understanding [sessions, users, and hits](http://cutroni.com/blog/2014/02/05/understanding-digital-analytics-data/) in Google Analytics. It should help clear things up for you.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading a lot about GA and testing stuff out the last two days now. This answer was useful, just to understand that nothing is sent unless one explicitly send events was really helpful (they don't put it straight forward like that in the docs). The last article you posted was also very helpful! Thanks!